# Disable 3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA cipher in etcd Kubernetes

Tags: security, ssl, kubernetes, tls1.2, etcd

while evaluating the network security using nmap on Kubernetes server, we noticed a warning as below

~]# nmap xxx.xx.xx.xx -p 6443 -sVC --script=ssl*

```
.
.
.
ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
```

With bit of research got to know that **TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - C** cipher suite is to support 64bit block SSL/TLS Handshake and the suggested solution is to disable the cipher option in Kubernetes etcd. please help me how to do it.

other views on this much appreciated, please let me know what is the better way to secure the environment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--cipher-suites` CLI option to etcd. See https://etcd.io/docs/v3.4/op-guide/security/ for a summary of all their TLS config options. The default ciphers is based on the version of Go used to compile it.

Comment: Following above doc, under spec.containers.command in /etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml I added below entry and restarted the etcd, nothing changed
- --cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,